# how to get selected value from table based on dropdown selection in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript. I am trying to filter selected values of selectbox dropdown in table based on selection from another selectbox dropdown outside table. 
We have already selected values in selectbox inside table like selected values for id="billStat1" is 'open' , for id="billStat2" is 'verified'.

So, if we select from id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn" and the value is 'open' , then get rows `<tr>` containing selected values as 'open', remaining rows `<tr>` should hide .

like if we select 'open' from selectbox(id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn") then in that case we have only `1st <tr>` and `3rd <tr>` which contain the selected values as `'open'`, so that row , should show, other rows  should hide.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <select class="form-control" id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn">
         <option value="Open">Open </option>
         <option value="Verified">Verified </option>
          <option value="Rejected">Rejected </option>
         </select>
        <table class="table">
        <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select class="form-control" id="billStat1">
      <option value="Open" selected>Open</option>
     <option value="Verified">Verified</option>
      <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select class="form-control" id="billStat2">
      <option value="Open" >Open</option>
     <option value="Verified" selected>Verified</option>
      <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select class="form-control" id="billStat3">
      <option value="Open" selected>Open</option>
     <option value="Verified">Verified</option>
      <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select class="form-control" id="billStat4">
      <option value="Open" selected>Open</option>
     <option value="Verified">Verified</option>
      <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
        </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#verglobalFIlterDropdwn').on('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    /*logic to get row of table containing selected values same as values from id='verglobalFIlterDropdwn' selectbox.
    case1: If selected values from id='verglobalFIlterDropdwn' selectbox equals already selected values of select in table row, then show it otherwise ,hide other row not containing values of select same as id='verglobalFIlterDropdwn' selectbox
    
    */
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: your question is not clear, what do you wanna do when an option is selected in drop down.

Comment: We have already selected values in selectbox inside table like selected values for id="billStat1" is 'open' , for  id="billStat2" is 'verified'. So, if we select from id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn" and the value is 'open' , then get rows containing selected values as 'open', remaining rows should hide .

Comment: like if we select 'open' from selectbox(id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn") then in that case we have only 1st <tr> and 3rd <tr> which contain the selected values as 'open', so that row <tr>, should show, other rows <tr> should hide.

Answer (score 1):

you can just select all the rows inside table and hide them, then iterate over all the selects and compare their values to `$("#verglobalFIlterDropdwn")` and based on that you can show parent row. something like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select class="form-control" id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn">
 <option value="" selected> </option>
 <option value="Open">Open </option>
 <option value="Verified">Verified </option>
  <optionvalue="Rejected">Rejected </option>
 </select>
<table class="table">
<tbody
<tr>
<td>
<select class="form-control" id="billStat1">
  <option value="Open" selected>Open</option>
 <option value="Verified">Verified</option>
  <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="form-control" id="billStat2">
  <option value="Open">Open</option>
 <option value="Verified" selected>Verified</option>
  <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="form-control" id="billStat3">
  <option value="Open" selected>Open</option>
 <option value="Verified">Verified</option>
  <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="form-control" id="billStat4">
  <option value="Open" selected>Open</option>
 <option value="Verified">Verified</option>
  <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#verglobalFIlterDropdwn').on('change', function() {
   //console.log(this.value);
   var selectedValue = this.value;
   $('.table tr').hide();
   if(!selectedValue)
     $('.table tr').show();
   var selects = $('.table .form-control');
   for(var i=0; i<selects.length; i++){
     if($(selects[i]).val() === selectedValue)
        $(selects[i]).parents('tr').show();
   }
});
$('#verglobalFIlterDropdwn').trigger('change');
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: We dont need to hide whole table, we need to hide table 'tr' based on selection from id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn". If the value from, this id, matches with the selected value in table row <tr> then show <tr> and hide other <tr> which are not containing the selected value from id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn".

Comment: the code is not hiding the whole table just the selects.

Comment: we need to hide table rows if values dont match .

Comment: Thanks, Please tell how you do that.

Comment: you can just select all the rows inside table and hide them, then iterate over all the selects and compare their values to `$("#verglobalFIlterDropdwn")` and based on that you can show parent row

Comment: But the code lacks one thing, suppose if the id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn" contains first option as empty,nothing, then whole table is lost because it gets null value. How to control that if, there is null or empty value in option of id="verglobalFIlterDropdwn" ?

Comment: then what do you want to do in that case

Comment: it shows complete table now in that case, check code.

Comment: yes, thanks , good logic to hide all the rows and then show them if certain conditions are met. Thanks

Comment: @ManzerHashmi can you see if this solution is working for you or not? If it is working, you should atleast accept it.